# How to use imblearn undersampler in pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, imblearn

I have the following pipeline construction:

```
    from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
    from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline


    sel = SelectKBest(k='all',score_func=chi2)
    under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.2)
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols)])
    final_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('sample',under),('preprocessor', preprocessor),('var',VarianceThreshold()),('sel',sel),('clf', model)])
```

however i get the following error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps of the chain should be estimators that implement fit and transform or fit_resample (but not both) or be a string 'passthrough' '<class 'sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector'>' (type <class 'type'>) doesn't)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

@Math12, I have encountered this same issue recently and the way I got around it, is to wrap the RandomUnderSampler() in a custom function which is then further transformed by a FunctionTransformer.

I have reworded your code to look this way and it worked.

Below is a snippet of the code sample

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline


sel = SelectKBest(k='all',score_func=chi2)
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols)])

def Data_Preprocessing_3(df):
    # fit random under sampler on the train data
    rus = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.2)
    df = rus.fit_resample(df)
    return df

# in a separate code line outside the above function, transform the function #with a FunctionTransformer
under = FunctionTransformer(Data_Preprocessing_3)

#implement your pipeline as done initially
final_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('sample',under),('preprocessor', preprocessor),('var',VarianceThreshold()),('sel',sel),('clf', model)])
```

Comment: Alignment of the code is not okay.